# MS Excel custom formatting left to right

Tags: excel

Need help regarding excel custom format, there used to be a symbol to format from left to right.

ex.
123456789 -> format 0-0-000 -> would be 12345-6-789

I'm looking for
123456789 -> format [unknown command]0-0-000 -> would be 1-2-3456789

I just can't find them.
Need them in custom format and not in VBA for the sake of frustration can't finding it. Thanks

Comment: There is no such symbol, as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 0):

This should work: **#-#-#######**

What is important is that the number of hash keys should correspond to the length of your number -> length of, or number of characters in, 123456789 is 9, the same as the number of hash keys above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional formatting to achieve what you need.

1. Select your data (let's say it's A1-A5)
2. Open Conditional Formatting > New rule
3. Select the last type "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
4. As a formula type `=LEN(A1)=5`
5. Open Format, select Custom and use `0-0-000`
6. Confirm everything
7. Repeat steps 2-6 as long as you need changing formula to `=LEN(A1)=6`, `=LEN(A1)=7`... and format to `0-0-0000`, `0-0-00000`...

Answer (score 0):

0-0-0000000 is working for 9 digits numbers but for shorter like 12345 it will be 0-0-0012345